$g$ lies in the centre of $G$ iff $\vert\chi(g)\vert=\vert\chi(1)\vert$ for all irreducible characters $\chi$
I have been trying the following exercise (Chapter 3, Exercise 10) from Webb's "A Course in Finite Group Representation Theory".

Let $g\in G$. Show that $g$ is in the centre of $G$ if and only if $\vert\chi(g)\vert=\vert\chi(1)\vert$ for every simple complex character $\chi$ of $G$.

I have proved the forward direction (since elements of the centre act by scalars), but I have not shown the converse. I tried to use the regular representation of $G$, but I cannot show that $g$ must act by a scalar in this case as well (even though it does on the constituent irreducibles, these scalars may vary).
Any hints would be appreciated. The question differs from this one since we don't have a faithfulness hypothesis.

Let $\rho$ be the $n$-dimensional irreducible representation with character $\chi$. If $|\chi(g)|=|\chi(1)|=n$, since $\rho(g)^m=\rho(g^m)=\rho(1)=1$ for some $m$, the eigenvalues of $\rho(g)$ are $n$ roots of unity, say $\lambda_1, \cdots, \cdots, \lambda_n$. Hence $|\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\cdots+\lambda_n|=n$ while $|\lambda_i|=1$. Therefore all $\lambda_i$'s are linearly dependent as $2$-dimensional real vectors. That is, $\lambda_i = a_i \lambda_1$ where $a_i\in\mathbb R$, and $a_i\equiv 1$ or $a_i\equiv -1$. So $\rho(g)=\lambda_1I_n$ or $\rho(g)=-\lambda_1I_n$. Hence $\rho(g)$ commutes with $\rho(h)$ for all $h\in G$.
Now it follows that $g$ commutes with all $h$ based on the fact that all irreducible representations put together is faithful.

Here is a nice fact to know: for any irreducible character $\chi$ and any $g,h \in G$ we have $$\chi(g)\chi(h) = \frac{\chi(1)}{|G|} \sum_{z \in G} \chi(gzhz^{-1}).$$ I'll leave the proof as an exercise. Taking the above for granted, we get $$\sum_{\chi} |\chi(g)|^2 = \sum_{\chi} \chi(g)\chi(g^{-1}) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{z \in G} \sum_{\chi} \chi(1) \chi(gzg^{-1}z^{-1}) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{z \in G} |G| \delta_{gz,zg} = |Z(g)|.$$ In the third equality we have used that $\sum_{\chi} \chi(1)\chi$ is the character of the regular representation. Now if $|\chi(g)| = \chi(1)$ for all $\chi$, then we get $|Z(g)| = \sum_{\chi} \chi(1)^2 = |G|$, so $g$ is central.
